# How can one prove that $f(x) = 4x - \ln(x^2 + 1)$ is injective?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = 4x - \ln(x^2 + 1)$.      Prove that $f$ is injective.

How I thought to solve this problem was to use the derivative of the function and show that it is strictly positive and strictly increasing, thus demonstrating that $f(x)$ is in fact strictly increasing and this in turn proving that the function is injective, but I got stuck on showing that the derivative is strictly increasing.

$$f'(x) = 2\frac{2x^2 - x + 2}{x^2 + 1}$$

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $a > b$.

$$f'(a) > f'(b) \Longleftrightarrow 2\frac{2a^2 - a + 2}{a^2 + 1} > 2\frac{2b^2 - b + 2}{b^2 + 1}$$

And here is where I got stuck.

Comment: You don't need to show that the derivative is increasing.  The fact that it's always positive is sufficient.

Comment: @B. Goddard right I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: Think about $f(x) = \ln x$.  It's strictly increasing and its derivative is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @B.Goddard Now that I think about it, it does make sense because if you know the derivative in a point is positive it means the "next" point will be "higher" so if the derivative is greater than $0$ in every point this means no point has a "lower" point in front of it so the function is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $2x^2-x+2$ and $x^2+1$ are always positive and hence $f'(x) >0\ \forall\ x \in\mathbb R$.

So, $f(x) $ is always increasing.

Comment: Wait the derivative doesn't have to be strictly increasing as well, it only has to be strictly positive for the function to be strictly increasing?

Comment: That's what I said in the answer, no difference. :-)

Comment: @MarcGrec That's right, consider a simple example of an increasing function like $f(x)=x^3$.  $f'$ is strictly positive but definitely not increasing!

Answer (score 2):

Your derivative is:
$$f'(x) = 2 \dfrac{2x^2-x+2}{x^2+1}$$
Notice that denominator is $> 0$ and the numerator is a quadratic in $x$ whose discriminant is
$$D = (-1)^2-4.2.2 < 0$$
Thus $$2x^2-x+2 > 0$$
Hence $$f'(x) > 0$$